# In survey data, do you trust variables whose estimates differ substantially from authoritative sources?

Tags: r, mixed-model, survey, small-area-estimation

I have data from a large-scale health survey and am interested in using it to predict certain outcomes in new populations.

However, I'm concerned with several variables that seem to "miss the mark" when comparing to authoritative estimates. For example, the income distributions skew low, and urban/rural indicator skews rural. Notably, the survey's sample weights do not use income or rurality as a raking factor.

Unsurprisingly, my model-based estimates for target population subgroups compare quite well with authoritative sources *when utilizing only variables that the sample weights incorporated as weights* (county, age, sex, education, etc.). However, when I include the unraked variables, they compare poorly.

In the toy example below, `input1` is an example of a variable used to calculate `weights`, whereas `input2` was not. Obviously this example doesn't incorporate standard errors or formal tests, but I hope it nonetheless gets the point across.

Should I jettison `input2` as being incomparable across populations? Note that I'd prefer to include it as it improves the predictive power of the model.

```r
# Reproducible example
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
set.seed(6646)

# Survey microdata
sv <- data.frame(county = rep(1:4, 25),
                 outcome = rbinom(100, 1, .45),
                 weights = rep(10:14, 20),
                 input1 = runif(100)/2 - 0.25,
                 input2 = runif(100)*3)

# Population microdata are similar to survey data...
pop <- sv
# ...except they have different values for input2 (drawn from the same distribution)
pop$input2 = runif(100)*3

# Weighted full-sample means ae equivalent for input1, upon which weights were raked...
weighted.mean(sv$input1, w = sv$weights)
#> [1] 0.03111552
weighted.mean(pop$input1, w = pop$weights)
#> [1] 0.03111552

# ...but they differ substantially for the unraked input2
weighted.mean(sv$input2, w = sv$weights)
#> [1] 1.647157
weighted.mean(pop$input2, w = pop$weights)
#> [1] 1.571213

# What are we to make, then, from a weighted mixed effects model with independent variables input1 and input2?
lmer1 <- glmer(outcome ~ (1|county) + input1 + input2,
               data = sv,
               weights = weights,
               family = binomial(link = "logit"))
summary(lmer1)
#> Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
#>   Approximation) [glmerMod]
#>  Family: binomial  ( logit )
#> Formula: outcome ~ (1 | county) + input1 + input2
#>    Data: sv
#> Weights: weights
#> 
#>      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#>   1624.9   1635.4   -808.5   1616.9       96 
#> 
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>    Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
#> -5.073 -3.297  2.130  3.279  4.860 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#>  county (Intercept) 0.01247  0.1117  
#> Number of obs: 100, groups:  county, 4
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)  0.54835    0.14134   3.880 0.000105 ***
#> input1       2.27348    0.45034   5.048 4.46e-07 ***
#> input2      -0.33560    0.07044  -4.764 1.90e-06 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#>        (Intr) input1
#> input1  0.026       
#> input2 -0.813 -0.149
pop_p <- predict(lmer1, newdata = pop, type = "response")
pop_p[1:10]
#>         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
#> 0.6717459 0.4037756 0.5880819 0.3861082 0.5039683 0.3236325 0.4358122 0.6723534 
#>         9        10 
#> 0.6034128 0.4416004
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How much (not whether) to trust estimates that differ from other populations is a tricky question. The problem is similar to the one of figuring out an informative prior in Bayesian statistics, but it comes up, regardless of whether you are Bayesian, frequentist, or some other school.

How well done was your sampling?  Was it from a different population? You mention that income skews low (which would be very unusual) and rural/urban skews rural.  Well, those might be related. Doubtless income distribution is different in rural and urban populations and, while I don't have data, it wouldn't surprise me at all if it was found that the typical right skew in income is (at least, in the USA and similar places) mostly due to urban populations -- rich people like to live in cities. New York City and the Bay area of California have a huge over-representation among the Forbes 400, which would certainly add right skew!  And, while the *owners* of large farms may well be wealthy, they often don't live on the farm, and agricultural work is usually fairly low paying. Another issue is that most large prisons and jails are in rural areas--were incarcerated people included in your study? How about the well known ones?

So, how well done was your sampling? This is something that requires a lot of thought and insight, in most cases.  There are all sorts of issues such as non-response, finding the appropriate population, sampling appropriately (was it simple random sampling? Stratified? Cluster? If it was anything other than simple random, were appropriate adjustments made?)

And so on. (This answer was just what I came up with in 10 minutes; there are lots of other issues too).